# SQL Query Inner Join and OR

Tags: sql, oracle

How do i select using `INNER JOIN` and `OR`, i tried using below query but it doesn't return anything also no error

```
SELECT * FROM chatroom_message cm
INNER JOIN users_account ua
ON cm.userid_a = ua.reg_userid 
OR cm.userid_b = ua.reg_userid 
WHERE cm.userid_a = :chat_client OR cm.userid_b = :chat_client
```

Comment: I added the oracle tag based on the parameter formatting. Please change it if that assumption is incorrect.

Comment: It doesn't work like that as far as I know, the OR will filter, you might use Union instead, see if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19725014/sql-server-left-join-with-or-operator

Comment: Do you get results w/o the where cluase?  I'm suspecting the :chat_client is invalid

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM chatroom_message cm INNER JOIN users_account ua ON cm.userid_a = ua.reg_userid 
INNER JOIN users_account ub ON cm.userid_b = ub.reg_userid 
WHERE cm.userid_a = :chat_client OR cm.userid_b = :chat_client
```

The change here is 2 joins, one join per user on the user table. This is because you have 2 user ids in the message table that are different (no one chats to themselves) so you need a join for `userid_a` and another join for `userid_b`.

The join you had was effectively returning 0 records because `userid_a` will never equal `userid_b`. Also you do not want an `OR` in your `WHERE` clause for *this* query.

The `WHERE` clause was fine.

Comment: This worked, please i have another issue i rand into can you help out?

Comment: @PhilipJems - Once the 15 minute grace period has expired please consider marking an answer using the chekmark on the right side. If you have another question please post a new question on [so], adding new questions to an existing one is generally frowned upon unless it is closely related or something that came up during discovery (*ie. some asked a question in the comments section and you are answering them but have a question about it*).

Comment: I am surprised this got accepted. The join in OP's query should be no problem, as it is `OR` not `AND`: `ON cm.userid_a = ua.reg_userid OR cm.userid_b = ua.reg_userid`. So a record with *either* `userid_a`matching *or* `userid_b` matching would be selected.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner - I am thinking the `OR` in the JOIN clause was actually an `ON` but was incorrectly copied/pasted.

Answer (score 3):

`Igor`'s answer is the straightforward way, but I am thinking of getting rid of `OR` which is usually associated with poorer performance and UNION the results for each `reg_userid`. Something like the following:

```
SELECT * FROM chatroom_message cm
INNER JOIN users_account ua ON cm.userid_a = ua.reg_userid 
WHERE cm.userid_a = :chat_client
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM chatroom_message cm
INNER JOIN users_account ua ON cm.userid_b = ua.reg_userid 
WHERE cm.userid_b = :chat_client
```

Although this might be faster, the data for a specific `chatroom_message` is slightly harder to get, as it is split between 2 records. It depends on what you are doing with this data afterwards.

Comment: Actually I used your code in my system, but i marked him as answered because his answer was first

Answer (score 0):

You will need two inner joins for this to work -- One for userid_a and another for userid_b.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say `:chat_client = 123`. Then you'd select all `chatroom_message` records where `userid_a = 123` plus all `chatroom_message` records where `userid_b = 123`.

```
userid_a  userid_b
111       222         <- this one not
333       123         <- this one yes
123       444         <- this one yes
```

To these records you join `users_account`. This gets you:

```
userid_a  userid_b  username
333       123       Mr. 333
333       123       Mr. 123
123       444       Mr. 123
123       444       Mr. 444
```

So if you don't get any records, then there simply is no `chatroom_message` record for user 123 (or there is no matching entry in `users_account` which should be impossible due to foreign key constraints.

The query is fine. Check your parameter and data.