# SQL Join Including NULLs

Tags: sql-server, join, null

Using SQL Server Management Studio 2016 (v 13.0).

I have two tables with two distinct keys I can use to join, with the catch being that there are mixed NULLs in both PK columns:

```
Table 1          Table 2    

Acct1  App1      Acct2  App2    Product
-----------      ----------------------
1      A         NULL   A       Bed 
2      B         2      B       Sofa
3      C         3      NULL    Bed 
4      D         4      D       Bed
```

Desired result in the joined table, only including those where Product = Bed:

```
Acct  App  Product
1     A    Bed 
3     C    Bed 
4     D    Bed
```

Thank you!

Comment: You can make this question better by answering the following two questions: What have you tried? What is the error you get?

Comment: Unless your problem is specifically related to SSMS, you should mention the version of SQL Server that you are using, not the version of SSMS. SSMS 2016 can be used to access SQL Server versions fropm 2005 to 2016, so if you have a t-sql problem we'd rather know what version of SQL Server you have. An answer for SQL Server 2016 might not be appropriate if you're using SQL Server 2008,

Answer (score 3):

While I agree @d219's answer should be the correct solution, a different approach could use an `or` in the `join` such like:

```
select Acct1,App1,Product 
from table1 inner join table2
on App1=App2 or Acct1=Acct2 
where Product='Bed'
```

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19725014/sql-server-left-join-with-or-operator) for discussion on using the `or join`.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to do two separate `SELECT` statements using each key and then `UNION` them, something like this:

```
SELECT t1.Acct1, t1.App1, t2.Product
FROM Table1 t1
INNER JOIN Table2 t2
ON t1.Acct1 = t2.Acct2
WHERE t2.Product = 'Bed'

UNION 

SELECT t1.Acct1, t1.App1, t2.Product
FROM Table1 t1
INNER JOIN Table2 t2
ON t1.App1 = t2.App2
WHERE t2.Product = 'Bed'
```